# ERROR: traefik, xdbautomationworker, Container is unhealthy

Tags: docker, sitecore

Trying to create sitecore 10 image using Docker on Windows 10 Enterprise locally but getting unhealthy containers. Please help me out as I have tried various steps that was updated in the forums.

Getting below errors:

```
Creating network "sitecore-xp0_default" with the default driver
Creating sitecore-xp0_solr_1  ... done
Creating sitecore-xp0_mssql_1 ... done
Creating sitecore-xp0_id_1        ... done
Creating sitecore-xp0_solr-init_1 ... done
Creating sitecore-xp0_xconnect_1  ... done
Creating sitecore-xp0_cm_1        ... done

ERROR: for cortexprocessingworker  Container "992574e988e3" is unhealthy.

ERROR: for xdbautomationworker  Container "992574e988e3" is unhealthy.

ERROR: for xdbsearchworker  Container "992574e988e3" is unhealthy.

ERROR: for traefik  Container "933b548fc2f9" is unhealthy.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Checked the following things:

```
docker-compose stop on Powershell.

docker-compose down on Powershell.

iisreset /stop on Powershell to make sure that the required ports are free.

docker-compose up -d on Powershell.

Stopped, removed the container and executed the command docker-compose.exe up --detach multiple times but no luck.
```

Comment: The traefik container will always be unhealthy if one of the dependent on new are unhealthy, so I wouldn't focus on that. Should each of the xconnect workers not be on a separate container? Reason I ask is the error shown for each references the same container id 992574e988e3. Are you able to see any logs for container 992574e988e3?

Comment: Hello Dean, Is there any command to check logs for unhealthy container ?

Comment: For your example, the following should work: docker logs 992574e988e3

Comment: Alternatively, if you select the container as it is starting up in 'docker for windows' it should stream the logs to the console

Comment: Dean, I have checked the logs for the unhealthy container (Now the container has been changed, docker logs 115700a28139 )   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Data.SqlServer.Configuration.HealthChecks.SqlShardClusterHealthCheck.<CheckHealthAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
2021-10-25 21:05:13.258 +03:00 [Error] Health check "Collection shard cluster health check" completed after 14904.4575ms with status Unhealthy and 
'"Health check for shard cluster is failed."'

Comment: 2021-10-25 21:16:57.331 +03:00 [Error] Health check "Web controllers health check" completed after 14846.6899ms with status Unhealthy and '"Type ContactsController can not be instantiated."'
2021-10-25 21:16:57.331 +03:00 [Warning] Readiness health check run has been canceled by timeout (30 sec)
2021-10-25 18:16:57 ::1 GET /healthz/ready - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT;+Windows+NT+10.0;+en-US)+WindowsPowerShell/5.1.17763.1971 - 504 0 0 30736

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the .env file and make sure SITECORE_LICENSE has a value.

You may need to run the init.ps1 file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs now provided in the comments above, my suggestion would be to check the collection SQL connection string, to the shardsmanager database.

You can inspect the SQL container in docker for Windows and find the IP address of the SQL server. Connect to that using ssms and try connecting with the creds you have in current string.

Edit: looking again at the exception, it looks like it can't find the SQL server. Yet the CM server appears to not have a problem finding the same server. So compare the web/master/core connection string to the collection one. I'm guessing the SQL server portion will be different?